# mysql truncate archive table

Tags: mysql, archive

I have a table with the **archive** storage engine and I would like to clear it. Neither `delete`, nor `truncate` will work because of the engine definition. But is there any other way than dropping the whole table an recreating it?

Comment: I guess you could just do that, drop the table and recreate it, but why wouldn't `DELETE FROM table` work?  What engine are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Bug #15558 truncate doesn't clear table on archive storage engine tables](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15558)

Basically, the designers wanted it to work that way.  The fix to that bug was to make it return an error when you try to use truncate on a table stored with the ARCHIVE storage engine.

The only workaround is to DROP and the re-CREATE the table.

Comment: I hoped that there was some kind of workaround for this issue ... Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

Another workaround would be to change it to be a BLACKHOLE table, then change it back.

Comment: After testing this I found that it is effective. The .ARZ file is reset without needing to recreate the table definition.

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Does the job. :)

Comment: `ALTER TABLE the_table ENGINE=BLACKHOLE; ALTER TABLE the_table ENGINE=ARCHIVE`

Answer (score 0):

DELETE or BLACKHOLE solutions are slow on big tables. The fastest solution:
create table the_table2 like the_table; drop table the_table; rename table the_table2 to the_table;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).